# Move it inside the useMemo callback. Alternatively, wrap the initialization of 'COLOR_CODES' in its own useMemo() Hook react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**Plz help me how to solve the error**
*Move it inside the useMemo callback. Alternatively, wrap the initialization of 'COLOR_CODES' in its own useMemo() Hook react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*

```
    const pathColor = React.useMemo(() => {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    if (counter <= alert.threshold) {
      return alert.color;
    } else if (counter <= warning.threshold) {
      return warning.color;
    } else {
      return info.color;
    }
  }, [counter,  COLOR_CODES]);
```

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. Have you tried following its advice?

Comment: @CertainPerformance if i removed the COLOR_CODES form the dependency array the following error is  showing React Hook React.useMemo has a missing dependency: 'COLOR_CODES'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: Your `COLOR_CODES` should be memoized too - as it says.